# Group my-sql column objects of a model having same data on Django admin side

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin

I have a model with the following definition

```
class exam_questions(models.Model):
    exam_name=models.ForeignKey(exam,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question=models.ForeignKey(questions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'examquestions'
    unique_together = (("exam_name", "question"),)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s - %s' % (self.exam_name, self.question)
```

The data on sql table will look like this

```
+----+----------------+-------------+
| id | exam_name      | question    |
+----+----------------+-------------+
|  2 |          test2 |          29 |
|  3 |          test1 |          41 |
|  6 |          test2 |          40 |
|  7 |          test1 |          42 |
+----+----------------+-------------+
```

On Django admin I am looking the model objects like the following:

test2-29

test1-41

test2-40

test1-42

Now I want to group questions of same test and want to look them like the below:

test2-29,40

test1-41,42

I tried using normal python string operations, none of them worked on amdin django instead gave me errors.

Is there way for doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in django admin? If you group questions like this in admin, it will be impossible to edit them later. You can instead create `Exam` model and replace `exam_name` field with foreign key to it. Then you can use inlines to edit questions for each exam.

Comment: I want to manage the display and was checking if there is a possibility for this.People who use it without knowledge of object and model should get it easily. thats the intention. Would be great if an option to enter multiple entries for a reference field is possible

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Can you provide some example how list of questions in django should look like?

Comment: As I have given above, exam_questions can have an exam name and questions.one exam field can have multiple questions linked to it. I should be able to add all questions of 1 exam at a time or atleast should be able to see them together on admin

Answer (score 0):

```
You can override objects manager in this way  :- 
class ExamManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
       return super(ExamManager,self).get_queryset().group_by('exam_name')

class exam_questions(models.Model):
    exam_name=models.ForeignKey(exam,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question=models.ForeignKey(questions,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = ExamManager()
```

Comment: Got error like 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'group_by'. seems doesnt work